# Adding optional change event on html element and js function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events, onchange

I have an Angular popup component which is used for multiple types.

For types A and B I have an "action" section in footer, which is used to get results and close the popup. For type C, I want to close the popup when a checkbox is selected (so, here I need to use `change` event, but this is unusefull for types A and B).

html:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="max">
   <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell>Max</th>
   <td *matCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="row.actions.maxDisabled ? 'disabled' : ''"
         mat-cell>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="onActionSelected(row)"
                    [(ngModel)]="row.actions.max"
                    [disabled]="row.actions.maxDisabled"></mat-checkbox>
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

ts:

```
onActionSelected(row: any): void {
   if (this.source !== 'C') {
      return;
   }

   const data = this.dataSource.data;
   const value = Helpers.getValue(data);

   this.dialogRef.close(value);
}
```

I added `(change)="onActionSelected(row)"` event on my template only for case `C` and is required to check in the method if source type is another than it.

**I'm wondering if** exists a solution more elegant to add the change event dynamically to the checkbox and remove verification from the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a condition to your change event, assuming that the row object contains the source property:

```
(change)="row.source !== 'C' && onActionSelected(row)"
```

Comment: AKA Javascript [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation)